# Table do not Filter on button click using DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, mysql

I am new to this C# programming and currently student and we have a project on sorting a records using datetimepicker can you help me.
i have a class here that is binded to my datagridview

```
   public class Sales
{
    public int Trans_Code{ get; set; }

    public string Item_Name { get; set; }

    public string Item_Desc { get; set; }

    public string Item_Qty { get; set; }

    public string Item_Price{ get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

}
```

and this is my button on click the two datetimepicker named as `dtFromDate`(from this date) `dtToDate`(to this date).

```
    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string query = " SELECT * FROM tbl_sales WHERE Date BETWEEN '"+dtFromDate.Value+"' AND '"+dtToDate.Value+"'";
        salesBindingSource1.DataSource = conn.Query<Sales>(query, commandType: CommandType.Text);
        conn.Close();
    }
```

[this is the application and not sorting according to the datetimepicker on button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjOMJ.jpg)

[and this is my table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhQJB.jpg)

Comment: A WHERE clause does not sort results, it limits which rows will be included.  Also passing dates as text as you are is a bad idea.  SQL parameters allow you to write better code that users cannot crash or exploit

Comment: You haven't used any kind of *sort* and *order by* functions with your query, so why it should be sorted? Also you should always use parameterized queries to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: What should i try or do to sort it?

Comment: The very first thing you should do is stop and learn about SQL parameters/parameterized queries/prepared statements.  It is something the school ought to have covered but likely didnt.  Then look up how SQL `ORDER BY` works...I suspect you want both to limit rows to a date range **and** sort the results